# mongo cursor findOne

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to open a stream of data from mongoDB by querying a field with an array of values, and return only one record per index of array.

```
var cursor = Collection.findOne({'lastName': { $in: [arrayOfLastNames]}}).cursor();

  cursor.on('data', function (record) {
   //do something with record
  })
```

for whatever reason, it is pulling multiple records per index of arrayOfLastNames. The .findOne() method is behaving as .find() would. 
Any suggestions as to why this is happening, or possible alternatives to this implementation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why use a cursor at all, when you need just one item?

Comment: @qqilihq I need one record per item in the arrayOfLastNames. The reason for the cursor is because the quantity of data exceeds memory.

Answer (score 3):

You're running into issues because you used a cursor. From the [mongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/#the-findone-result-document), "You cannot apply cursor methods to the result of findOne() because a single document is returned."

From your comment, you want to call `findOne` once for every item in the array since `$in` with `findOne` will find the first document according to the "[natural order](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/glossary/#term-natural-order)" of the document that matches any item in the array (you might also consider just using a general `find` honestly, since then your cursor solution will work).